# Laplace transform of unit step function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Im given a graph of $f(t)$ and i need to find the Laplace transform of $f(t)$. From looking at the graph i have

$$f(t) =
\begin{cases}
t,  & \text{$0 \le t \le 1 $} \\
0, & \text{$1 \lt t \lt \infty$}   \\
\end{cases}$$

The previous problems ive worked all involved the unit step function, so assuming that's the right direction with this one, i setup $f(t)$ as

$$f(t)=tu(t)-tu(t-1)$$

Then
$$\begin{align}
F(s)&=\mathcal{L}\{tu(t)\}+\mathcal{L}\{tu(t-1)\} \\
 & = \int_0^1e^{-st}tdt-\int_1^\infty e^{-st}tdt \\ 
 & = \left(\frac{-1}{s}-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)e^{-s}-\int_1^\infty e^{-st}tdt \\
\end{align}$$

I dont know how to go any further, or if the setup is right?. The answer the book has is $$F(s)=\frac{1-e^{-s}-se^{-s}}{s^2}$$

Comment: The function you want to use is $f(t)=t(u(t)-u(t-1))$.

Comment: Ok, yes that makes sense after reading more about unit step function from a link someone else had posted. With the correct $f(t)$ i just get stuck now at the actual transform part. Ive updated my question.

Comment: Can you use a Laplace transform table?  The function above is only useful if you are using a table.  Otherwise just integrate from 0 to 1, i.e. $F(s)= \int_0^1e^{-st}tdt$.

Comment: Ive looked at tables, and i guess i am not experienced enough with these to know how to apply them here. (Would love to know how!) And cant figure out how to use integration by parts here, do i do it for both integrals?

Comment: Am i doing the first integral correctly? Do i apply the formula to that or to the second part ? Confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that this gets you going in the right direction:

$$\begin{align}
F(s)&= \int_0^1e^{-st}tdt \\ 
 & = \left.\left(\frac{-t}{s}-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)e^{-st}\right|_0^1 \\
 & = \left(\frac{-1}{s}-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)e^{-s} -\left(0-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\\
\end{align}$$

You should be able to get to the book answer from there.  I did the integration by looking it up in an integral table [here](http://integral-table.com/integral-table.html#SECTION00006000000000000000):

Comment: I got this above, its the $\int_1^\infty e^{-st}tdt$ part i dont get specifically.

Comment: The function is zero for $t>1$.  You don't need to integrate it.

Comment: How can you tell?

Comment: By definition: $f(t) =
\begin{cases}
t,  & \text{$0 \le t \le 1 $} \\
0, & \text{$1 \lt t \lt \infty$}   \\
\end{cases}$