# Inverse Laplace transform for $\frac{1-e^{-\pi s}}{s(s^2 + 16)}$

Tags: analysis, laplace-transform

I want to find the inverse Laplace transform for the following:$$\frac{1-e^{-\pi s}}{s(s^2 + 16)}$$

This was obtained from a piecewise function and required the heaviside step function to simplify.

I have two questions:

Question 1: Must this be solved using the heaviside step function in reverse.

Question 2: If so, is this usually/always the case?

---

I can see it may be a good idea to separate the top two terms, but I am unsure where to go from there. It would seem that the numerator can't have any terms divided out by a derivative, nor is it a standard expression since we have $e$ on the top, which makes me think that partial fraction decomposition won't work here.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You can split into partial fraction regardless. And the exponential term on top only shifts the function!

Comment: So I can run through with partial fraction decomposition, and it is fine? Are there exceptions to that? Wouldn't I get a really ugly solution? Also, what would I have. Since $(s^2 + 2)$ gives me a numerator of $As+C$ since we have a power of $2$, what would I get for a numerator with $e^{-\pi s}$?

Comment: Ignore the numerator. That's just a multiplication factor that you leave alone. Like this: $(1-e^{-\pi s})\cdot \frac{1}{s(s^2+16)}$.

Comment: Like this: $(1-e^{-\pi s})\cdot \frac{1}{s(s^2+16)}=(1-e^{-\pi s})(A/s+(Bs+C)/(s^2+16))$. Then after this is done, you can multiply back and get a shifted and unshifted term for each fraction.

Comment: @orion Oh, yes that does make sense! Thank you, I will post up an attempt answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be 
$$
G(s)=(1-e^{\pi s})F(s)
$$
where
$$
F(s)=\frac{1}{s(s^2+16)}=\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{s}{s^2+16}\right)
$$
so that the $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(F(s))=f(t)$ is
$$
f(t)=\frac{1}{16}\left(u(t)-\cos(4t)u(t)\right)=\frac{1}{8}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos(2\cdot 2t)\right)}_{\sin^2(2t)}u(t)=\frac{1}{8}\sin^2(2t)u(t)
$$
where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside step function. 
Thus
$$
g(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(G(s))=f(t)u(t)-f(t-\pi)u(t-\pi)=\frac{1}{8}[u(t)-u(t-\pi)]\sin^2(2t)
$$

Comment: Thank you, I will overview this and see how I do, and get back to you if I have any troubles