# Solve the following ODE: $\xi w'(x) = g(x) \mbox{ if } x > s,\xi w'(x) + \lambda w(x) = g(x) \mbox{ if } x \leq s. $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

## Question

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function (you may assume this function to be smooth), $\xi,s,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Consider the following ODE:

$$
\begin{cases}
\xi w'(x) = g(x) & \mbox{ if } x > s\\
\xi w'(x) + \lambda w(x) = g(x) & \mbox{ if } x \leq s.
\end{cases}
$$

We look for a solution $w$ of this equation which is continuous (in particular at point $s$).

### Start of possible solution

As suggested in the comments:

one can define the [heaviside step function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html) as $u: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. This way we can rewrite the ODE as:
$$
\xi w'(x) + g(x) = \lambda u(x-s) w(x).
$$
Applying the Laplace transformation on both sides yields:
$$
\xi (t\mathcal{L}\{w\}(t) - w(t)) + \mathcal{L}\{g\}(x) = \lambda \mathcal{L}\{u(x-s)w(x)\}(t),
$$
but then I'm stuck as I don't know how to write $\mathcal{L}\{u(x-s)w(x)\}(t)$ write out write out $\mathcal{L}\{u(x-s)w(x)\}(t)$ i.f.o. $\mathcal{L}\{w\}$.

Comment: Do you know how to use Laplace transforms for systems of ODE's?

Comment: No, I indeed think this could be very useful, do you know of a good reference for this

Comment: When I google it, I'm mainly confused by the fact that the differential equation I give here consists of two parts, which makes me unsure about how to apply the theory.

Comment: I think I found a source:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022536/using-laplace-transforms-to-solve-a-piecewise-defined-function-initial-value-pro

Comment: Using the heaviside function $u$, we can rewrite the function as $\xi w'(x) - g(x) = - \lambda w(x) u(s-x)$. Then we can apply the Laplace transform on both sides, but I don't know what the laplace transform of $w(x) u(s-x)$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the differential equation
$$aw'\left( x \right)+b\theta \left( c-x \right)w\left( x \right)=g\left( x \right)$$ 
where $\theta \left( x \right)$is the unit step function.  For now we will assume the boundary value $w\left(0\right)$ is known.

Observe:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left( w\left( x \right){{e}^{\frac{b}{a}\int\limits_{0}^{x}{\theta \left( c-t \right)dt}}} \right)=\frac{1}{a}g\left( x \right){{e}^{\frac{b}{a}\int\limits_{0}^{x}{\theta \left( c-t \right)dt}}}$$
where
$$\frac{b}{a}\int\limits_{0}^{x}{\theta \left( c-t \right)dt}=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   \frac{b}{a}x & x<c  \\
   \frac{bc}{a} & x>c  \\
\end{matrix} \right.$$

Now
$$w\left( x \right)=\left( w\left( 0 \right)+\frac{1}{a}\int\limits_{0}^{x}{g\left( t \right){{e}^{\frac{b}{a}\int\limits_{0}^{t}{\theta \left( c-s \right)ds}}}dt} \right){{e}^{-\frac{b}{a}\int\limits_{0}^{x}{\theta \left( c-t \right)dt}}}$$
We have therefore 
$$w\left( x \right)=w\left( 0 \right){{e}^{-\frac{b}{a}x}}+\frac{1}{a}\int\limits_{0}^{x}{g\left( t \right){{e}^{\frac{b}{a}\left( t-x \right)}}dt}$$      for $x<c$
$$w\left( x \right)=w\left( 0 \right){{e}^{-\frac{bc}{a}}}+\frac{1}{a}\int\limits_{0}^{x}{g\left( t \right)dt}$$      for $x>c$

This is not, however, continuous at $x=c$. Continuity seems to imply conditions on $g\left( x \right)$.

Comment: How did you find the expression for $w(x)$ in the fourth equality?

Comment: Okay I got it, thanks!